# Multiple compile errors with to do list application - learning - new to objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I started going through this exercise using Xcode 4.6.3. I have since moved to Xcode 6 under Yosemite. Its obvious things have changed between these two versions of Xcode as it seems I am getting different errors through the code validator.

I would appreciate some guidance through this if possible.

Attached is a screenshot of the errors I am getting. I will also upload my source to view as well.

Screenshot
https://www.evernote.com/l/AJj3KH7xsmBFW4w4mT6i-6SrV6ySmJea4CU

Source
https://bitbucket.org/mlavender/to-do-list-app/src

I really appreciate any help that I can get.

Code for reference

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface AddToDoItem : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;


@end

@implementation AddToDoItem


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
    self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
    self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
}
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to include the errors and the code in the question itself, not link to an outside resource

Comment: Xcode 4? That's far too old. You need to upgrade to Xcode 6 otherwise you are wasting your time learning a lot of obsolete tools and language features.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question and include the code there.

Change `NSObject` to `UIViewController`, re build, that should clear most of your errors.  It's hard to tell what will be left over once you do that.

You also need to add an `@property` for `toDoItem`.  That's why it can't find `self.toDoItem`.

I would very strongly suggest running through some tutorials that can walk you through basics like this.  I learned tons from http://raywenderlich.com/ when I was getting started.

Comment: gotta love raywenderlich!